# How to store a time_t field to MySQL datetime?

Tags: mysql, linux, datetime, time-t

I have extracted the modification time of a file using the `struct stat` structure:

```
long modtime = image_stats.st_mtime;
```

This returns `1508240128`.

Now, I wish to store this value into a MySQL table which has datatype as datetime.
If I store it directly, it fails saying it is not a datetime format.

How do I store it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FROM_UNIXTIME to convert a timestamp into a DATETIME

**Query**

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1508240128);
```

**Result**

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(1508240128)  
---------------------------
2017-10-17 13:35:28
```

as insert query

**Query**

```
INSERT INTO 
 [table]
(datetime_column)
VALUES
 (FROM_UNIXTIME(1508240128))
```

Comment: Thanks it works great. `INSERT INTO commits (file_id, image_dir, modification_time,last_updated_by) SELECT file_id, '/opt/insiteone/images/PHAH00', FROM_UNIXTIME(1508240128), 'jbNotify' FROM vna.files WHERE image_proxy_name='PHAH0006.118';`